# Retrieve Client ios app certificate

Tags: ios, certificate, burp

I want to proxy traffic from an ios application to Fiddler (or Burp). It looks like the application sends a client certificate to the server.

I will need to retrieve this cert from the phone(it's jailbroken) and import it to my proxy. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The *client certificate* is used to identify the client. If the programmer of the app made his job well, you will face difficulties (hopefully). Likely, and most secure, the private key and identity resides in the key-chain. Less secure, it resides in a secured archive (.p12, .pkcs12, .pfx) in the bundle, whose password resides in the key-chain.

If the programmer did his job not so well, you might find the password of the secured archive in the clear somewhere in the apps binary (there're actually floating samples around which do exactly this).

Comment: shouldn't the cert be present on a tcpdump ? I actually tried to recover it but for some reason i only see an empty entry on the certs that the client sends (although the handshake works fine in the end)